# File.SetCreationTime works on Debug but not when I drag the move the Application

Tags: c#

```
        string loc = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(loc);
        Random rnd = new Random();
        foreach (var item in filePaths)
        {
            DateTime dt = new DateTime(rnd.Next(1990,2010), rnd.Next(1,12), rnd.Next(1,31));
            File.SetCreationTime(item, dt);
            File.SetLastAccessTime(item, dt);
            File.SetLastWriteTime(item, dt);
        }
```

This is my program to change CreationTime, AccesTime and WriteTime for all files which are in the application path. 
For example when I debug this code and put a picture in the debug folder the code works perfect. 
But when I copy the .exe and put it in a random folder it doesn't work anymore. 
Ist AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory blocking me or do you find any mistakes in this code? It should be super simple...

Comment: So have you checked what `loc` equals to?

Comment: you should rather specify the path or take it as input instead of `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`

Comment: So your question is *Why won't Windows let me do foolish things with my code like randomly modify all files in any folder I want?*?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well i know what caused the problem.
It does everything fine until he wants to change his own SetCreationTime.
That's when he stops working.

```
            foreach (var item in filePaths)
        {
            char sep = '\\';
            string[] mimi = item.Split(sep);
            if (mimi[mimi.Length - 1] == System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName) { continue; }


            DateTime dt = new DateTime(rnd.Next(1990, 2010), rnd.Next(1, 12), rnd.Next(1, 31));
            File.SetCreationTime(item, dt);
            File.SetLastAccessTime(item, dt);
            File.SetLastWriteTime(item, dt);
        }
```

So that did the trick for me. 
If the name of the application is equals the name he wants to work with --> go to next. 
Somehow folder dates are still unchanged but that doesn't matter to me.
So thanks for your attempts. ^^